# How does combat with weapon and shield work?

Tags: combat, ars-magica-5, shield

In Ars Magic 5th I am not able to find how combat works for a character with weapon and shield.

Attack total is:

> Dexterity + Combat Ability + Weapon Attack Modifier + Stress Dice

Defense total is:

> Speed + Combat Ability + Weapon Defense Modifier + Stress Dice

If a character fights with a sword and a shield, does it add both Defense Modifiers? Is the same done with Attack Modifiers?

Comment: I have spanish edition, so I needed to translate it back to english. Probably it is a fault on my side.

Comment: I'm removing the tag again, and removing the instructions you wrote in the tag wiki to use both tags, because it's unnecessary to overtag questions. If people want to find all questions about *Ars Magica*, they can search/favourite `ars-magica*`.

Comment: Should you, then, remove the double tag from all `ars-magica-5` questions?

Comment: @Envite Probably most of those questions aren't about every edition and so the tag doesn't belong, but digging through old questions just to fix one tag is a waste of people's time and eyeballs on the front page (since editing bumps questions). They'll get removed organically as they return to the front page or as people trip over them while looking for other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the English language edition, on page 171, under "Combat Scores" it says "If the character is using a weapon and a shield, add together the modifiers of the weapon and the shield to get the final modifier."

So, yes, add both modifiers to both totals.

Comment: As far as I can see the rules do not, however, consider the case where a combatant is fighting with two Single Weapons; or worse fighting Sword and Dagger, although I think that style may be anachronistic for the setting.

Comment: Thanks! I'll double check the possibly corresponding paragraph in spanish.

Comment: Found it. Correct.